# Decimal points in bitcoins

Tags: ticker

I would like to know if there are more than one decimal in bitcoin numbers. While playing online slots with Bitcoin, I hit a big win for 100900 x 5 credits totaling 5207.17.The total was displayed as 5,207.17 Please explain to me how this is supposed to exactly read.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A Bitcoin is divisible down to 8 decimal places (that is x.xxxxxxxx).

Comment: I was quite positive the formula you provided is correct due to where the decimal point is located. I won that amount and was given 5BTC, which I know is 5.00000000 or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Its common for sites to measure coins in milli- or micro-bitcoins, one milli-bitcoin is a thousandth of a bitcoin while a micro-bitcoin is a millionth of a bitcoin.

1 BTC = 1,000,000 µBTC (micro-bitcoin)

1 BTC = 1,000 mBTC (milli-bitcoin)

1 µBTC = 100 Satoshi

I'm not sure what website you are using, but I would hesitate a guess that those "credits" are mBTC, so 5207.17 is 5.20717 BTC which is around $40,000 USD at current rate, does that sound right?

Comment: I have seen mBtc, but this was not the case for me. I was playing with BTC.

Comment: You did not win 5,207.17 BTC though, that would be nearly $40 million dollars. Updated my answer though.

Comment: The date was 31 July and I was paid 3 Aug at the Bitcoin somewhere near $2732., and at that time, I was roughly around $14,000,000. at which point, I lost my breath. The win was in Bitcoin and not mBTC. I have never used MBTC at this particular business, and I was not educated on BTC. I just knew how to convert from BTC to USD. Long story short, I believe that I was not paid what I actually won.

Comment: Looking over my history, I was always paid what I won with no questions, and all wins were in BTC with the exception of the big one that was the only win converted to mBTC. It is evident by my deposit and withdrawal history and my BTC wallet.

Answer (score -1):

There are 8 decimal places behind the decimal point to a bit coin.

There are only 2 decimal places behind the decimal point, legally allowed to equate the Australian dollar.

There fore if your rates notice not invoice depicts the R.I.D rate in dollar as

00.00466450
X        Deliberatly Under valued home to 1/3 C.I.V:-
$333k
= $0

And 1 million bit coins 1,000,000. equals $1.

0.00 is netural  and any  further decimal place is a negative , a  negative  x a positive is always a negative figure .
Bit coins another sad furphy